# Rails use nesting and resource path with other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such method controller:

```
class Admin::CarManufacturersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @man = Manufacturer.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => 'admin'
  end

  def update
    @man = Manufacturer.find(params[:id])
    if @man.update_attributes(params[:car_manufacturer])
      ****
    else
      render :action => :edit, :layout => 'admin'
    end
  end
end
```

and i have such route:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :car_manufacturers do
    ###
  end
end
```

and such form partial:

```
= form_for [:admin, @man] do |f|
  ###
```

but when i call this form to edit my data i get:

```
undefined method `admin_manufacturer_path'
```

but i need admin_car_manufacturer_path i thing it's becouse i use other model name in controller, but i can't change it... how can i use right pass? i try to write admin_car_manufacturer_path in form, but i think this is bad idea. How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would think about renaming your controller/your model to match. Both should either be just manufacturer or car manufacturer. Having the same names for a resource's controller and model will spare you problems like the one you're having right now.

In any case, if you just need a quick fix, you can get around this by specifying the `as` option for your nested routes like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :manufacturers, as: :car_manufacturers do
    ###
  end
end
```

Source: [Rails Routing from the Outside In - Ruby on Rails Guides - 3.6: Naming Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

That will turn your path names into `admin_car_manufacturer_path` etc and should allow you to use your form the way you you intended to. But I really recommend renaming your model and controller so that they match.

Comment: then i get uninitialized constant Admin::ManufacturersController

Comment: i could rename controller to manufacturer, but how to be, if i have model called Model, and Type (car theme), it's breaking rails rules...

Comment: why not just do `namespace :admin do
  resources :car_manufacturers
end
`
and then use `admin_car_manufacturer_path`?

Comment: becouse namespace :admin do resources :car_manufacturersdo
      resources :car_models do
        resources :car_types
      end  end
    end

Comment: i have deep nesting and need to do, as i asked )